# Simple short rate model that generates ZCB skew

Tags: interest-rates, models, volatility-skew

Which is the simplest short rate model that generates ZCB vol skew ?
I want to use it afterwards and do simple "on paper" qualitative development about its dynamic(I don't need a model I can calibrate or price)

Thanks

Comment: Bachelier or shifted lognormal model for the short rate.